# Display score using spritesheet

Tags: lua, coronasdk, sprite, sprite-sheet

I would like to know how to display a score using a spritesheet. My game is about point collecting and I want to have this energybar to fill up. When the energybar is full an empty one pops up, the full one will disappear for end-game purposes. The spritesheet I have consists of 70 png images.

I could build it up using if-statements but there has to be a better way. Otherwise it would look something like this

```js
if score == 0 then
    display.newImage("00.png", x, y)
end
if score == 1 then
    display.newImage("01.png", x, y)
end
if score == 2 then
    display.newImage("02.png", x, y)
end
if score == 3 then
    display.newImage("03.png", x, y)
end
...
if score == 70 then
    display.newImage("70.png", x, y)
end
```

When the score is 71 it displays "01.png"

Comment: 71 -> 01.png, what about 141, 211, 281, etc..., 01.png too?

Comment: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newProgressView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be a direct relation between score value and filename you are using (meaning that 00 -> '00.png', 1 -> '01.png', ... 70 -> '70.png' etc), and after score=70, the whole sequence repeats, one way of doing this would be to firstly, getting rid of multiplies of 70, then just appending 0 in front for single digit score. Here's a function that does just that:

```
-- Given a score, returns correct picture name
-- eg. for score = 01 returns 01.png
local function getFilenameFromScore(score)
    while true do
        if score < 71 then break end

        -- get rid of multiplies of 70 by reducing score by 70
        -- until it's 0-70
        score = score - 70
    end

    -- if score is between 0 and 9 (one digit, so length is 1)
    -- add 0 in front
    -- this could also be done with modulo %
    if string.len(score) == 1 then
        score = '0' .. score
    end

    -- append .png and return
    return score .. '.png'
end
```

And later, show score as follows:

```
local scorePicture = getFilenameFromScore(score)

display.newImage(scorePicture, x, y)
```

Here, scorePicture will depend on score value in the way you described.